# Why is Yes case sensetive?

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and I am having trouble getting the result I want from a simple If /Else statement.

When "Yes" is entered correctly as written It works but I would like the response to work regardles of case sensitivity (i.e yes, YES, yEs etc.)

```
let cheer = prompt('Did the Team win?');

if(cheer != 'Yes') {
    alert("We will win the next one!");
} else{
     alert("Lets Go Team");
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) and/or [`.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase).

Comment: `window.prompt` returns a string. Whether or not you compare it to `Yes`, `yes` or whatever else is up to you. Strings in Javascript are case sensitive. The [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) should be used to compare strings regardless of the casing.

Comment: `'Yes'` is case-sensitive as all strings are case-sensitive to most any computer language.

Computers don't understand the context of human language.  They do literally what you tell them.  You'll have to do a case-insensitive comparison if that's what you want.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I was not aware of localeCompare, thanks for that!   That will save me a lot of hassle.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
let cheer = prompt('Did the Team win?');

if(cheer.toLowerCase() != 'yes') {
    alert("We will win the next one!");
} else{
    alert("Lets Go Team");
}
```

Comment: Amazing! thank you so much. I was nervous to ask my first SO question but this was perfect and a fast response too!

what would  .toLowerCase() be called ? I tried reasearching some things for myself but I dont think i was searching the right key words

Comment: @MAppel you're welcome. If this solves your problem, It is better to accept the answer so that others can use it.

Comment: @MAppel `.toLowerCase()` is one of the functions of a text string.

Comment: SO is telling me I can accept the answer in 5 mins and I surely will. Thank you for this additional advice!